# Pyqt5 QStandarditemModel get item index

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QStandarditemModel within a tabelview, as simply showed below:

```
model = QStandardItemModel(0, 4)
table = QTableView()
table.setModel(self.model)
```

Then, I add q QCombobox in a row

```
x2 = QComboBox()
tabel.setIndexWidget(model.index(1, 1), x2)
```

I am trying to get the row index of the item (Combobox). I tried to use

```
item = sender()
tabel.Indexof(item)
```

Is there a way to get the row index on selecting that QComboBox

Comment: There's no direct access to that, you have to track it in some way. A simple dictionary might do the trick: each time you create a new widget, use something like `self.widgetMapping[widget] = (row, column)` (it's better to use table coordinates, instead of QModelIndexes), then you can get the index back with `model.index(*self.widgetMapping[self.sender()])`. Remember that `setIndexWidget()` should be used with care, and it's usually better to use an item delegate instead, and then [`openPersistentEditor(index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#openPersistentEditor) eventually.

Comment: PS: don't try "random" functions blindly. Read and search in the documentation instead: in your case, the pages related to [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) and its ancestor [QAbstractItemView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the row there are several methodologies:

- Use a dictionary: Map the widgets in a dictionary to associate the key to the widget and the value to the row (and/or column):

```py
self.d = dict()
x2 = QComboBox()
tabel.setIndexWidget(model.index(1, 1), x2)
self.d[x2] = (row, column)
```

```
o = sender()
pos = self.d.get(o)
if pos is not None:
    row, col = pos
    print(row)
```

- Use geometry:

```py
o = sender()
if isinstance(o, QWidget):
   ix = tabel.indexAt(o.pos())
   print(ix.row())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I was missing is tabel.row(). Many Thanks